# Trying to get ALL crashes in Android

Tags: java, android, crash, splunk, uncaught-exception

My company is developing a complex android project which is not available on google play. They sell tablets with the app already installed and the updates are done through our ftp.

Recently we've started having some sporadic crashes in field, that never happen when the tablet is connected to the computer (so I can never see the logcat). So I've implemented a crash report system that sends the logcat file and crash report through email, with uncaughtExceptionHandler called in onCreate of the main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handleAppCrash);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handleAppCrash = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            #crash report stuff here
        };  
};
```

Although pretty much all crashes are getting caught with this method, that specific and sporadic one which I'm searching for is not. The 'app has stopped' dialog appears, but this method is never called. After this I started using Splunk Mint (http://www.splunk.com/en_us/homepage.html), hoping that the library was more powerful, but I have the exact same behavior.

So my question is: which type of crashes are not caught with this uncaughtExceptionHandler? Could be a crash on Java itself? Is there a way to go around this to understand where the crash comes from?

Thank you!

Comment: have you read http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29

Comment: yes... there's something I'm missing there?

Comment: I think so, check code of this library https://github.com/ishratkhan/RuntimeCrashHandler